# Select fields not being added when adding columns with the addSelect function from a model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So i am trying to include a custom field called `status`, created a scope for it so it is reusable. But when adding the field the other fields of the given model aren't being queried.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
...
/**
 * Scope include something.
 */
public function scopeIncludeSomething(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->addSelect(DB::raw('(field_two * field_two) as something'))
}
```

So when I query the model with some fields selected e.g.:

```php
Model::includeStatus()->get(['field_one', 'field_two']);
```

Then this is being returned:

```
[
  0 => array:1 [
    "something" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "something" => 3
  ]
]
```

I can add the columns of the model in the addSelect statement, but I want to set them in the get function on the model. So this does work:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
...
/**
 * Scope include something.
 */
public function scopeIncludeSomething(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->addSelect(DB::raw(', (field_one * field_two) as something'))
}
```

```
Model::includeStatus()->get(['field_one', 'field_two']);
```

```
[
  0 => array:3 [
    "something" => 16,
    "field_one" => 4,
    "field_two" => 4
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "something" => 4,
    "field_one" => 2,
    "field_two" => 2
  ]
]
```

Anyone who knows a solution to this so the get function on the model still selects the columns you pass in it.

Comment: Why don't you use the `select` method instead of `get` in getting the fields. `Model::select(['field_one', 'field_two'])->includeStatus()->get();`

Comment: One is IncludeSomething and the other is IncludeStatus…